# Access - combining multiple columns into multivalued fields?

Tags: ms-access

I'm somewhat new to Access, so I'm hoping my question will be a simple one to answer...

I have a table that looks approximately like this:

```
 PairID  | MaleCode   | FemaleCode
 A-01    | SR         | BB
 A-02    | SG         | SB
 A-03    | SM         | GB
 B-01    | GR         | BR
 B-02    | RR         | RB
```

I'd like to either combine the male and female columns into a single column with multivalued fields or create a table that looks like this:

```
 PairID  | Code
 A-01    | SR
 A-01    | BB
 A-02    | SG
 A-02    | SB
 A-03    | SM
 A-03    | GB
 B-01    | GR
 B-01    | BR
 B-02    | RR
 B-02    | RB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO newTab (PairID, Code) SELECT PairID, MaleCode FROM oldTab
INSERT INTO newTab (PairID, Code) SELECT PairID, FemaleCode FROM oldTab
```

You can either write a macro that runs these two SQL lines together, or create two queries to run each line separately.

Comment: Did this help Mirabilis? If you have any questions or need any more help please ask :)